# Преобразование из long

Tags: c#, vknet

Возникла ошибка в программе, прошу разобраться. Вот скриншоты ошибки и ее места в коде:

[image: Скриншот 1]

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так, `VkNet`, смотрим документацию - `Users.Get(([NotNull] IEnumerable<long> userIds, ProfileFields fields = null, NameCase nameCase = null)` - уже по множественному числу можно понять, что функция имеет дело со множеством пользователей и действительно - сигнатура требует `IEnumerable<long>` на вход. Так что в случае с одним единственным пользователем нам все равно придется поместить его в какую-то коллекцию (любой объект реализующий `IEnumerable<long>` подойдет). Возьмем обычный массив. Идем простейшим путем и пишем:

```
var thisUser = Users.Get(new[] {uid}).FirstOrDefault();
```

На выходе функции тоже будет массив так что с помощью `FirstOrDefault()` получаем первый же (и единственный) объект класса `User` , или `null` если пользователей с таким `uid` нет. Дальше уже обращайтесь к полям этого объекта, я просто не знаю его структуру, но там наверняка есть искомое поле `Name`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wkhHm24A
Залил код
Если можно, код сразу, хочу просто понять как именно решается данная проблема. Думаю не поверите, но я с ней всю ночь сижу)

Comment: Я понял. Сейчас все будет)

Comment: Спасибо большое, надеюсь поможете.

Comment: Поправил ответ. Пробуйте

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ib7mfn добавив ваш код, появилась еще одна ошибка.

Comment: Вы невнимательны. Я же сказал - на выходе будет объект класса User.

Comment: Никак не string

Comment: я даже специально написал отдельную переменную!

Comment: Все, спасибо, разобрался.